# How to make a network interface unavailable to all but one process

Tags: linux, networking, systemd

In an embedded project I'm using 5 modems. One main modem for OTA upgrade, remote SSH, sending data on the cloud, etc. And 4 modems for network survey (reading signal strenght, making speedtest, on each network operator in my country).

My main modem (wwan-main) have a sim card with a subscription with a lot of data available. 4 other modems (wwan-aux) have sim card with a very limited amount of data available.

I want to be sure that, even if my main-modem fails, applications other than my network-survey process will never use the wwan-aux interfaces to send data.

I've defined metric, wwan-main with metric 10 and wwan-aux with metric 50, but if my wwan-main failed, the system will use the next available interface, so wwan-aux and I don't want that.

Do you have any solution for this?

Comment: Linux network namespaces: meant exactly for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> even if my main-modem fails, applications other than my network-survey process will never use the wwan-aux interfaces to send data.

So just do not add default route via these interfaces, so that they will never picked.

Comment: Thanks I didn't thought about it.
I've test it but the problem is without a route, it seems I can not use my interface. And I can not create a route manually cause I don't know the IP address (it's provider dependant and change at each boot).
Sorry, I'm now very good in ICT

Comment: Then you are contradictory. Either you want to use an interface, or you don't. You can add route for specific address. `I can not create a route manually cause I don't know the IP address` so.. write a parametrable script that will take the dynamic ip and execute your custom action. `/etc/ppp/if-up.d/` for ppp

Comment: Maybe my explanation was not good (my english is bad, sorry). I want my "wwan-aux" interface be used only by one specific process. Other process (system, mender, thingsboard, etc) can absolutely not use it. I will try your solution  adding a specific route. Thanks

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/271915/route-the-traffic-over-specific-interface-for-a-process-in-linux Add the default route only to a specific rt_tables and make that specific process use that table. It's still _a lot_ of work. You could restrict the access by routing only a specific ip address you want to access, it would be simpler.

Comment: Ok, so I've removed the default route, and create route manually. I tried with systemd, but it seems you have to create route only when the interface is up. I you create it before the interface is fully up, the route will not work. So I create the route after set my interface up. And it do the job. Thanks for your help !